# Issue with encoded array from php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I'm having an issue returning a value from PHP to Javascript. I have encoded the PHP array like so :

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

And on the Javascript side i do this within the $.ajax method:

```
success:function (data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

This works and it alerts the returned array, however when i try to then set my Javascript array to the value of data :

```
success:function (data) {
  myArray = data;
}
```

This completely breaks my looping operation and so instead of printing out for example:

> This is a test

It will print:

> t,h,i,s,i,s,a,t,e,s,t

and the length of the array rather than being 4, for 4 words it is 16+ including the square brackets etc. How can i reuse the json encoded array once it has been recieved by javascript and maintain its structure?

Comment: You probably need to to do myArray = JSON.parse(data); Since it is technically coming in as a string, not as an object.

Comment: you were right that fixed it, if you post it as an answer i will accept it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

What you are looking for:

`myArray = JSON.parse(data);`